# How to show that linear span in $C[0,1]$ need not be closed

Tags: functional-analysis, approximation, examples-counterexamples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non-closed subspace of a Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177923/non-closed-subspace-of-a-banach-space)

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed space over $\mathbb{R}$. I want to find a set of vectors $(x_k)$ such that the linear [span](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span#Definition) of $(x_k)$ of vectors is not closed.

I feel like the set $P$, which conists of polynomials in $X=C[0,1]$ (with the sup-norm) would be a good candidate since the Weierstrass approximation theorem yields that the span of $P$ is dense in $X$. How can I show that this span is not closed?

Comment: Do you know what "closed" and "dense" mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can take your favourite convergent sequence of polynomials (e.g. partial sums of $\exp x = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$) and then prove that the limit is not in the span.

This proves the span is not sequentially closed. Since $X$ is normed, it follows that the span isn't closed.