# Suppose that $H$ is an infinite dimensional normed vector space, is every infinite dimensional subspace of $H$ with a basis closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $H$ is an infinite dimensional normed vector space, is every infinite dimensional subspace of $H$ with a basis closed?

In finite dimension, this is correct, but in infinite dimension, is this right?

Comment: No: it's not true in infinite dimension. Anyway, assuming AC, every subspace of $H$ has a basis.

Comment: Some additional facts that may help to understand the situation in infinite dimenson: a proper subspace is never open. The closure of every subspace is itself a subspace.

Comment: What sort of basis? A Hamel basis or something like a Hilbert basis?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177923/non-closed-subspace-of-a-banach-space

Comment: Seconding @DanielFischer's request for clarification: what _sort_ of basis? An algebraic basis? (Which always exists, by Axiom of Choice), or some presumed more-general analogue of an orthonormal "Hilbert space" basis in a Hilbert space? (Plus, not assuming your space is complete complicates the question even for pre-Hilbert spaces...) Can you clarify?