"Every linear subspace of a closed space is closed"
I am wondering how to show something that my book writes about $L^2$ and Hilbert spaces. First I will talk about what my book does:

It defines what a random variable in $L^2$ is.
It shows that $L^2$ is a normed linear space with an inner product: $\lVert X\rVert^2=\langle X,X\rangle=E[X^2]$and $\langle X,Y\rangle=E[XY]$.
It shows that $L^2$ is complete.
Hence by 3 it is a Hilbert space.
From there on they talk about Hilbert spaces not necessarily $L^2$-spaces.
If $\mathcal{L}$ is a subspace the define the distance $d(x,A)=\inf \{\lVert x-y\rVert: y\in \mathcal{L}\}$.
Then they have the sentence "Note that if $\mathcal{L}$ is a subspace then $x\in \mathcal{L}$ iff $d(x,\mathcal{L})=0$ (recall that a linear subspace of a closed space is always closed)"
Then they prove that if $\mathcal{L}$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ and $x \in \mathcal{H}$, there is an unique vector $y \in \mathcal{L}$ such that $\lVert x-y\rVert=d(x, \mathcal{L})$. Here they use that $\mathcal{L}$ is closed.

I am wondering how do we show the sentence in point 7:  (recall that a linear subspace of a closed space is always closed)?
Does this hold for all subspaces of Hilbert spaces? I know that it holds in the finite dimensional case?, but is $L^2$-finite dimensional?
The book is out online here:
https://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~lachout/Vyuka/O-Sem/JacodProtter2004.pdf
The chapter starts on page 189.

The assertion $x\in\mathcal L\iff d(x,\mathcal L)=0$ is correct, but the assertion “a linear subspace of a closed space is always closed” isn't.

Use \langle and \rangle for the angle bracket delimiters, not < and >. Likewise, use \lVert and \rVert for the double bar delimiters, rather than ||. (\lvert and \rvert produce single bar delimiters).

@Smiley1000 Did you check the PDF? Take a look at Definition 22.3. For the authors of this textbook, subspaces are closed by definition.

@JoséCarlosSantos Thank you, I didn't look that up. It's an unusual definition.

@JoséCarlosSantos Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it.

@JoséCarlosSantos But if subspaces are assumed to be closed, the claim "a linear subspace of a closed space is always closed" is also true by definition.

@Smiley1000 Indeed. I missed that.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177923/non-closed-subspace-of-a-banach-space for a subspace which is not closed.

@Smiley1000 thank you

@温泽海 thank you!

The book is misleading. Let me quote Definition 22.3:

A subset $\mathcal L$ of $\mathcal H$ is called a subspace if it is linear (that is, $x, y \in \mathcal L$ implies $αx+βy \in \mathcal L$) and closed (that is, if $(x_n)_{n≥1}$ converges to $x$ in $\mathcal H$, then $x \in \mathcal L$).

This means that the authors use the word "subspace" as a synonym for "closed linear subspace". This wording is perhaps a bit exotic, but everybody is free to give definitions.
The statement

Note that if $\mathcal{L}$ is a subspace then $x\in \mathcal{L}$ iff $d(x,\mathcal{L})=0$

is correct, simply because $\mathcal{L}$ is closed. Nothing else is needed here, and the "explanation"

recall that a linear subspace of a closed space is always closed

is not only superfluous, but also does not make sense as it stands. The words "linear subspace" and "closed space" have not been used before, thus they leave scope for interpretation.

The word "closed space" most likely means "closed subspace". However, using "closed" is redundant in the sense of the above definition.

The "recall" sentence could mean that a linear subspace (in the usual sense) of a closed linear subspace is closed. THIS IS WRONG.

It could mean that the authors erroneously wrote "linear subspace" instead of "subspace" in their sense. Then the claim is true - but superfluous.


